# MapActivity class in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator

when i extends the MapActivity class it shows an error.

error is:
cant resolved datatype. why?

how to add a maps.jar in my project?

thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably haven't done the steps required to set up a Maps project as described in [Maps External API Overview](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). There is no maps.jar to add. Read the document I linked to, and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

Google Map View :
[Creating a Map Activity](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code :

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Locale;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.location.Address;
    import android.location.Geocoder;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
    import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

    public class MyMapsActivity extends MapActivity 
    {    

            MapView mapView;
        MapController mapController;
        LocationManager locationManager;
        LocationListener locationListener;
            /** Called when the activity is first created. */
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
                 {
                   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                   setContentView(R.layout.main);

                    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
                    // enable Street view by default
                    mapView.setStreetView(true);

                    // enable to show Satellite view
                   // mapView.setSatellite(true);

                  // enable to show Traffic on map
                   // mapView.setTraffic(true);

                    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

                    mapController = mapView.getController();
                    mapController.setZoom(5); 


       locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  

       locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
      LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
      0, 
      0, 
      locationListener);

    Touchy t = new Touchy();
    List<Overlay> overlayList = mapView.getOverlays();
    overlayList.add(t);

}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


class Touchy extends Overlay
{
 public boolean onTap(GeoPoint point, MapView mapView) 
     {
       Context contexto = mapView.getContext();
       String msg = "Latitude : " + point.getLatitudeE6()/1E6 + " - " + 
                    "Longitude : " + point.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;

      Toast toast = Toast.makeText(contexto, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
     toast.show();

      return true;
     }
  }


   private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener 
   {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
    if (location != null)
    {
      GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
          (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
          (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
          "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + 
          " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      mapController.animateTo(point);
      mapController.setZoom(5);
      mapView.invalidate();
    }

      if (location != null)
      {
          GeoPoint point=null;
          String address = ConvertPointToLocation(point);
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }


    }

  public String ConvertPointToLocation(GeoPoint point) {   
        String address = "";
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
            getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
          List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
            point.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
            point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

          if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            for (int index = 0; 
        index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
              address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";
          }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {        
          e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        return address;
      }

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

} 
  }

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Layout Coding :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
               android:id="@+id/mapView"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:enabled="true"
               android:clickable="true"
               android:apiKey="Your MAP API Key"

    />

   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zoom" 
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Link for getting own API key process :

http://sanathnandasiri.blogspot.in/2011/04/obtaining-google-maps-api-key-for.html

Comment: How does this relate to the question at all besides usage of the `MapActivity` class?

Comment: @Praveen want to create map activity and I provide full source code. Now just ignore all errors.

Comment: You're not supposed to provide full source code in an answer. That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: What about @Jorgesys answer? He provide link that contain also some piece of code to create a map activity.
And Praveen didn't give description about his source code.
That's why I provide full source code. I don't think I were wrong and someone downvote my answer.