# android MapActivity can't be extends

Tags: java, android

I follow all the steps in these web-sites:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview

And I also downloaded the play-services-sdk.

However I still get an error message:

```
The import com.google.android.maps cannot be resolved
```

And I also can't extends MapActivity:

Here is my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sale"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.sale.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

         <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />  


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sale.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


              </activity>

         <!--  Entry for RegisterActivity.class -->
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
                  android:label="Register New Account"></activity>
        <meta-data android:value="@string/app_id" android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"/>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" android:label="Profile page"></activity>

        <meta-data
              android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
              android:value="AIzaSyDTVRXMTmfe3jZyAlt-87kRgqM8y4TzIto"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is the MapActivity that I start to create (however it doesn't recognize MapActivity):

```
package com.example.sale;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;  
import com.google.android.maps.MapView; 
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;


public class SaleMapActivity extends MapActivity {

}
```

What is the problem? I followed all the steps and read a lot in google, however without answer. How to solve it?

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282553/mapactivity-class-in-android

Comment: There are two mapping APIs: Maps V1 and Maps V2. You are confusing the two. Since Maps V1 is now deprecated, please use Maps V2. Maps V2 is documented here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/ If you visit URLs that have `v1/` in their path, you are in the wrong place.

Comment: hi i used the Maps v2 version as you can see from my manieft..i dont understand ,so what is the import that i need to write? it doesnt recognize my import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up both API's there are part in your code that are from Google Maps API V1 like:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

and more.

and also parts of API v2, what API v2 do you want to use?
I recommend you to stick with the Google Maps API V2, I wrote a blog post on how to implement google map API V2 in your app, you can check it out here:

[Google Maps API V2 Implementation](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: hi, i followed all the steps in your blog (and i find that i have no change in my code)..what am i doding wrong? what is the changes that i need to implement inorder to extends MapActivity?

Comment: MapActivity is Google API V1 object and cannot be used in V2. your activity should extend FragmentActivity and you sould use SupportMapFragment in order to show a map and Not a MapView. what more the coordinates object in this API is LatLng and not GeoPoint.

Comment: again, @AdirRahamim if you will follow directly all the step in the blog post you will end up with google maps API V2.

Comment: where does it wrote in the blog link what should i import? i even have not seen that i need to exetnds FragmentActivity in your blog? in your blog i can see only the xml...

Comment: well if you will actually read it you will see:
"8. Now create an Activity that extends from “FragmentActivity” , create an XML layout file
for this activity and set it as the content View of this activity, in the layout write the following:", and actually when i wrote this post i created a map application side by side with it and you can see the end result in the end of the post.

Answer (score 0):

This is prety much simple you are not required to download any thing
only the thing you required is to change the "Compile with"option to "googleAPIs" when you are creating a new project change it.